# Writing Function type in typescript: fat arrow and object literal type

Tags: typescript

I am learning Typescript and I read two ways to write the function type : with a fat arrow or with an object literal.

For example :

```
let myAdd1: (x: number, y: number) => number =
    function(x: number, y: number): number {return x + y; };

let myAdd2: { (x: number, y: number): number } =
    function(x: number, y: number): number {return x + y; };
```

What are the reasons to use one rather the other ?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are identical types written in different ways:

```
let myAdd1: (x: number, y: number) => number;
type Func = typeof myAdd1;
// type Func = (x: number, y: number) => number
let myAdd2: { (x: number, y: number): number };
type Callable = typeof myAdd2;
// type Callable = (x: number, y: number) => number
```

You can see that the compiler considers both `Func` and `Callable` to be of type `(x: number, y: number) => number`.  Since they're the same, reasons for preferring one to the other are probably subjective and opinion-based.

---

However, if you start adding properties to the function then the object notation is probably preferable as easier to represent:

```
let func1: ((x: string) => string) & { color: string } =
  Object.assign((z: string) => z.toUpperCase(), { color: "red" });
type FuncWithProp = typeof func1;
// type FuncWithProp = ((x: string) => string) & { color: string; }
let func2: { (x: string): string; color: string } = 
  Object.assign((z: string) => z.toLowerCase(), { color: "green" });
type CallableWithProp = typeof func2;
// type CallableWithProp = { (x: string): string; color: string }
```

The types `FuncWithProp` and `CallableWithProp` are no longer considered to be identical, but they are mutually assignable (meaning the compiler sees that each `extends` the other):

```
type MutuallyExtends<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = void;
type FuncVsCallableWithprops = MutuallyExtends<FuncWithProp, CallableWithProp>; // okay
```

So again you can probably use either one in principle, but the `FuncWithProp` is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) whereas `CallableWithProp` is a single object type which might behave better in certain edge cases.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAtgngggEwQRgFwQBQA90DsCuUARiAE4A0EMehJpAlBALwB8EBxZA3AFBgwAHEBABi+XAGNmEfkID2AM2jwkyXgHp1MwcLGTp2GpwpUjdRq3a0yPUJFiIEAJnQBvTDivHK1L+bNkEAC+vLLCAMIAhsDAkUSg0mGKyo5OGlphEFExcQlMHgEmvhzmzGwlNrbgEAriEmiYhhAAzmCkAJa4AOYWbK0d3YwAZBDuEnLAcqTo-Z1dwcw8EBAA8kQAViASYAB0kc3N7V24GBgAXjNtc70QZztgcgCqAkKkUc0gGPSUYxNT6AAiUggBAA4L0UI6UR1ADq7TAAAsAAqkOQCRI6ZK1SRqHiabRCaGSOGIlFogxNWaDMotK7Uka-SbTWkDLpcYJVSDYiQuUYFFnXS6s9njJlCuYLJhLVYbLa7faHY6nC4C6mWO4PAAycgA7mR3p9vnzRf8IACusCQLgwUEIXwodlYvEQCTkaj0fkkkpuWk8RkHdEnaBXWSPXzKXSeuLuiK-syqfMgjx7YSALL4MD4QMwACiWDAVoQzQAPAAVCAgfOF5oQR6UR4Vqu4IsQABqlFb0lLbHyADc5O0EJDCXoJK3mo7ci74QiBO6a-l05ns3mC82S6OQ+7KJPnVu0Sx2fi5ABrSIwZPJzIASQUOYAjlngDXixAABqUACalDg0nEJ9wXVcEoAAhaRcBAXtAh7HgMDLFgvhpctKzXFs3wgAB+CBkAgdAnEYFDq1g+DEMsZCmxbT9MOw3CIHwzC4HQEDeBTCIES2E8HyfeEYGkW8uOiEsvRqOpkEoYSfUoAFmkiKAQABKSEHaBQFDIK0wABFhLx4IA)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is a normal typed function declaration and assignment. The second example uses function overloads shorthand.

Consider we have some normal function overloads:

```
function myMultiAdd(x: number, y: number): number;
function myMultiAdd(x: number, y: number, z?: number): number {
    return x + y + (z ? z : 0);
}
```

Both `myMultiAdd(1, 2)` and `myMultiAdd(1, 2, 3)` will work. It's inconvenient to use this pattern when having many function overloads because we will repeat the same name again and again, thus typescript has a short function overloads syntax like this:

```
let myMultiAdd: {
    (x: number, y: number): number,
    (x: number, y: number, z: number): number
} = function (x: number, y: number, z?: number): number {
    return x + y + (z ? z : 0);
}
```

So, if you don't want to use function overloads, then you should always use the first example to type functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am sorry I could not accept TWO answers. However, your answer is very interesting.